# Spring data rest - Is there a way to restrict some operations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a entity User. Is there any way to restrict GET method on /users?

The reason I want it to be restricted is because the app is a multi tenant application. /users for example will fetch all users belonging to all tenants.

Comment: without knowing your implementation. It seems you need to implement Authentication and Authorization since this is the possible only way to restrict users from fetching all the data.

Comment: Yes, Authentication and Authorization is done. My question was not clear. The app is multi tenant and if I enable Spring Data Rest, /users for example will fetch all Users for all tenants. I wanted to know if I can block requests to /users or /products with Spring Security.